# gcc compiling -E, -S, -save-temps and -M options are not allowed with multiple

Tags: gcc, gnu-make, llvm-gcc

I am trying to compile code on a Mac (OS X 10.7.5)

I am stuck with a message, I don't know which action I should take to try to address or fix this.

I am fully aware that this is a little short, but basically the only message thrown to the console.

```
llvm-g++-4.2: -E, -S, -save-temps and -M options are not allowed with multiple -arch flags
```

Any leads on what this is tell me? (note that the code has compiled on similar environments)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any details about the build environment - I assume it provides a configure script - in most cases you can get around this issue by passing `--disable-dependency-tracking` to your configure options.

Prior to doing so, I would suggest cleaning the build directory entirely i.e. `make distclean`, if it is provided by the build structure.